# Ranking tf-idf scores in an array in R

Tags: r, tf-idf

I wrote the following the function to determine the tf-idf of a document:

Determine tf

```
tf <- function(specific_word, text){
 count = 0
 list = unlist(strsplit(text, " "))

 for(word in (list)){
  if(word == specific_word){
   count = count + 1
   }
  }
 hit_rate <- count/length(list)
 return(hit_rate)
}
```

Determine idf value

```
idf <- function(specific_word, texts){

  times_a_word_appears <- 0
  total_number_of_documents <- length(texts)

  for(document in texts){
    list = strsplit(document, " ")
    list = unlist(list)

    for(word in list){
      if(word == specific_word){
        times_a_word_appears = times_a_word_appears + 1
        break
      }
    }

  }
  times_a_word_appears = times_a_word_appears + 1

  idf = log(total_number_of_documents/ times_a_word_appears)
  return(idf)
 }
```

And finally - determining the tf-idf

```
tfidf <- function(specific_word, text, texts){

  x = tf(specific_word, text)
  y = idf(specific_word, texts)
  z = x * y

   print(paste0("The tf-idf value is: ", z))
}
```

I can now use this to determine the tf-idf value of fe these documents:

```
document1 = c("films is a 2000 made-for-TV horror movie directed by Richard Clabaugh. The film features several cult favorite actors, including William Zabka of The Karate Kid fame, Wil Wheaton, Casper Van Dien, Jenny McCarthy, Keith Coogan, Robert Englund (best known for his role as Freddy Krueger in the
A Nightmare on Elm Street series of films), Dana Barron, David Bowe, and Sean Whalen. The film concerns a genetically engineered snake, a python, that escapes and unleashes itself on a small town. It includes the classic final girl scenario evident in films like Friday the 13th. It was filmed in Los Angeles,
California and Malibu, California. Python was followed by two sequels: Python II (2002) and Boa vs. Python (2004), both also made-for-TV films")

document2 = c("Python, from the Greek word, is a genus of nonvenomous pythons[2] found in Africa and Asia. Currently, 7 species are recognised.[2] A member of this genus, P. reticulatus, is among the longest snakes known.")

document3 = c("The Colt Python is a .357 Magnum caliber revolver formerly manufactured by Colt's Manufacturing Company of Hartford, Connecticut. It is sometimes referred to as a Combat Magnum It was first introduced in 1955, the same year as Smith &amp; Wesson's M29 .44 Magnum. The now discontinued
Colt Python targeted the premium revolver market segment. Some firearm collectors and writers such as Jeff Cooper, Ian V. Hogg, Chuck Hawks, Leroy Thompson, Renee Smeets and Martin Dougherty have described the Python as the finest production revolver ever made")

texts = c(document1, document2, document3)
```

And find the tf-idf value of "films" in document1

```
word = "films"
relevant_text = document1
tfidf(word, relevant_text, texts)
```

However what I would like to now is loop over all words in all the documents to determine what are the highest rating words of the document.

So for document 1 a little like:

```
words = unlist(unique(strsplit(document1, " ")))

for(word in words){
  tfidf(word, document1, texts)
  }
```

But then the values should be stored in an array and ranked. A little like this in python:

```
scores = {word: tfidf(word, document1, texts) for word in document1.words}
sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Any thoughts on how this could be done most efficiently in R?

Comment: Are you set on doing this yourself? Is it an exercise? Otherwise you could use one of many existing implementations: `tidytext::bind_tf_idf`, `cleanNLP::get_tfidf`, `quanteda::tfidf`, or `tm::weightTfIdf`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855832/using-tf-idf-to-determine-the-important-words-in-a-conversation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look at the packages listed on the [CRAN Task View: Natural Language Processing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html). There are several packages that serve for the whole process of creating document term matrices including normalization or tfidf weighting. Their vignettes also demonstrate a lot of downstream tasks like regession models or clustering for classification, topic modelling, etc.

Below I have used one of the packages, i.e., `text2vec`, to solve your task of creating a tfidf weighted document term matrix.

I hope that helps.

```
library(text2vec)

#with your docuemnts...
#texts = c(document1, document2, document3)

#create iterator to split texts into tokens
iterator <- itoken(texts, 
                  preprocessor = tolower, 
                  tokenizer = word_tokenizer, 
                  progressbar = FALSE)

#create the vocabulary of tokens
vocabulary <- create_vocabulary(iterator)

#combine tokens into a document term matrix
#this will be a sparse matrix (see the package "Matrix" for details)
#you might need to convert your dtm objects with as.matrix() to "normal" matrices 
#depending on your downstream task (although most packages accept sparse matrices)
#note, that when converting with as.matrix(), you will loose the memory of advantage of sparse matrices
dtm <- create_dtm(iterator, vocab_vectorizer(vocabulary))
str(dtm)
# Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
# ..@ i       : int [1:192] 1 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 0 ...
# ..@ p       : int [1:173] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
# ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 172
# ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
# .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
# .. ..$ : chr [1:172] "recognised" "premium" "finest" "william" ...
# ..@ x       : num [1:192] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..@ factors : list()

#set up basic tfidf model
tfidf <- TfIdf$new()

#apply model to your dtm
dtm_tfidf <-  fit_transform(dtm, tfidf)

str(dtm_tfidf)
# Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
# ..@ i       : int [1:192] 1 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 0 ...
# ..@ p       : int [1:173] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
# ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 172
# ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
# .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
# .. ..$ : chr [1:172] "recognised" "premium" "finest" "william" ...
# ..@ x       : num [1:192] 0.01126 0.00461 0.00461 0.00322 0.00461 ...
# ..@ factors : list()
```